# How does a Rails app set its Environment (Dev., Staging, etc.)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, puma-dev

Having a very confusing issue

My local app is running in its `staging` environment.  I use puma-dev for the server and when I tail it by running `tail -f ~/Library/Logs/puma-dev.log` it says that the environment is development, but when I log out to my view using `<%= Rails.env %>` it says `staging` and the app tries to use any `staging` environment variables that it needs instead of the variables for the `development` environment.

The app has environments for `Development`, `Staging`, `Test` and `Production`.  It is only recently that I noticed this was running in staging, I'm not exactly sure how or when it switched over but for the last couple years it was running in dev just fine, I recently added a staging env to help with a rails upgrade and some point over the last week this started running in staging.

I always thought this was set by the server when started but with puma-dev saying its env is development. I am at a loss for how this is trying to run in staging.

puma-dev output when starting:

```
io[19626]: Puma starting in single mode...
io[19626]: * Version 4.3.5 (ruby 2.4.6-p354), codename: Mysterious Traveller
io[19626]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 5
io[19626]: * Environment: development
```

Can anyone shed some light on exactly where or how a Rails app decides to set its Environment because for the life of me, I cannot find it in the app.

As a test based on the answer below (which was useful) I log out these 3 variables:

1. `<%= Rails.env %>` which ends up being `staging`
2. `<%= ENV["RAILS_ENV"] %>` which ends up showing nothing
3. `<%= ENV["RACK_ENV"] %>` which ends up being `development`

Also, if I run the rails console and type in `Rails.env` is also returns 'development'.

I also used the suggestion in the answer below and ran `RAILS_ENV=development rails server`.  When doing that, both `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` and `ENV["RACK_ENV"]` were set to development but the application was still running in staging (so the first variable above didn't change but the second one did).

The app is still trying to use all the staging ENV variables that are set (S3, etc.).  For this app I also recently updated from Rails 3.* to 4.2 (I know these versions are old. I inherited the apps and am working on it).  Which was the reason for adding the staging Environment.  I was unable to find anything in the upgrade guides that talks about this kind of issue so I, at first, didn't suspect it was related but I wanted to give as much info as I could on this issue.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#creating-rails-environments

Comment: @tar ya man I already created the staging environemnt.  that isn't what my question is about at all.

Comment: @RockwellRice are you starting the server with `rails server -e staging`? Based upon your question, @tar's comment seems to be exactly what you need. Including more code in your answer will help us not assume you haven't done something.

Comment: @Chiperific I am not, the server is puma-dev and, as I CLEARLY mentioned in my question, it says it is running in development mode, which is why I am so stuck with this.  I am more than happy to include any related code that would help but I am not sure what that could be, what code would you like me to add to help?  I added the output from puma-dev and the commands I use to show env, anything else just let me know and I'll add it.

Comment: Given your update, something in an initializer is setting your local env to `staging`, fixing that might fix your headache. I'm guessing when you added your staging environment, you added a piece of code that is always setting you to staging.

Comment: can you check your puma.rb file?
if the env is set there

Comment: All I see is `environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }`.  Also, as I mentioned above, it says it is running in development, so it must be the app (I guess?) that is changing that at some point, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out today.

Since adding the staging environment to the application I guess I needed to add some config files inside a `puma` directory in the app itself to help puma figure out what it needed to do.

To be honest I'm still not sure why I needed this since puma would say it was running in development, which I thought was setting the environment.

What I did was add a `puma` directory inside the `config` directory and then I added a file named `development.rb` and in there put the setting for running in the development environment.

Content of puma/development.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env puma
root = "/Path/to/the/application"
daemonize false
environment "development"
directory root
pidfile "#{root}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
stdout_redirect "#{root}/log/puma_stdout.log", "#{root}/log/puma_stderr.log", true
workers 2
threads 8,32
bind "unix:///#{root}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"
bind "tcp://0.0.0.0:8080"
preload_app!
```

It nows runs as expected on my local machine.

Answer (score 4):

To make sure I'm clear:

- your local app is 'staging'
- you want your local app to be run in 'development'
- you see puma running in 'development', but the app seems to be pulling variables for 'staging'
- you want puma running in 'development' and the app to recognize that it's in 'development'

Puma is [setting its environment](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/12d1706ddc71b89ed2ee26275e31c788e94ff541/lib/puma/configuration.rb#L170) like this:

```
:environment => -> { ENV['RACK_ENV'] || "development" }
```

Rails sets `.env` [like this](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails.html):

```
# File railties/lib/rails.rb, line 73
def env
  @_env ||= ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(ENV["RAILS_ENV"].presence || ENV["RACK_ENV"].presence || "development")
end
```

So if `RACK_ENV` is `development`, but `RAILS_ENV` is `staging`, then they will mis-match.

Try:

```
RAILS_ENV=development rails server
```

Or, check the values of `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` and `ENV["RACK_ENV"]` while server is running.

Comment: Thanks for this.  So given your guidance here I did notice that `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` does not return anything but `ENV["RACK_ENV"]` returns development.  So something must have broken the first.   I will look into that.  Thanks again fro this explanation hopefully I can pull this thread.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing something you changed when adding the `staging` env is actually un-setting (or failing to set) `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]`, figuring this out might solve both your problems.